# Check is category parent with ids from the childs - get_term_children

Tags: categories, hierarchical, id, walker, children

I have a hierarchical category list, like:

```
A (Parent Category)

 - B (Child Category)
 - C (Child Category)
 - D (Child Category)

B (Parent Category)

 - E (Child Category)
 - F (Child Category)
```

And i will, that if the Parent Category has Children Categorys, that then the Parent Category have the ID'S also of the Child Categorys, like

```
<input id="parent_1(ID)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="parent_1(ID)" checked="checked" onchange="toggle( 1 (ID of the Parent Category), Array( 4, 3 (Both ID's of the Child Categorys), 999 ) )">
```

So that when Parent Category is check, the child Categorys also checked.

With the old function of Wordpress get_children_categories worked as expected, and java makes the rest with check the childrens by recognizing the id.

But my Problem is, that the function get_children_categories is depraceted and with the new function get_term_children its not work.

The old code looked so:

```
class Walker_Category extends Walker 
{
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');

    function start_lvl($output, $depth, $args) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return $output;

        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
        return $output;
    }
....................

function start_el($output, $category, $depth, $args)
    {
        extract($args);
        $cat_name = esc_attr($category->name);

        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
        $children = substr( get_category_children( $category->term_id, '', ', '), 0, -2 );
li><input type='checkbox' onchange='toggle( {$category->term_id}, Array( $children, 999 ) )'

.................
```

But when i changed the code like:

```
$children = get_term_children( (int) $category->term_id, $category);

"<li><input type='checkbox' onchange='toggle( {$category->term_id}, Array( $children...
```

It gives only a 0 out. When i print_r than outputs arrays with the id's of the children categories, like:

```
 $children = get_term_children( (int) $category->term_id, 'category');

 $children = print_r( $children );
```

And the output is:

```
 Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => 6 ) Array ( )
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can release it? I'm already a few hours on it and come not forward with it. Or there may be another solution whereby the sub-categories are also checked. Thanks for the help ...

Answer (score 1):

Sry, here is my answer:

Here is first the output for listing the category in checkbox:

**Walker for the Category Output**

```
class Adv_Multicheck_Walker_Category extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id');

    function start_lvl($output, $depth, $args) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return $output;

        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
        return $output;
    }

    function end_lvl($output, $depth, $args) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return $output;

        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";

        return $output;
    }

    function start_el($output, $category, $depth, $args) {
        extract($args);
        $cat_name = esc_attr($category->name);
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
        $checked = '';
        if ( empty($_GET['s']) || $_GET["adv_cat_{$category->term_id}"] == 'on' )
                    $checked = 'checked="checked"';

        $output .= "<li><input type='checkbox' class='cb-element'  checked='checked' name='adv_cat_{$category->term_id}' id='adv_cat_{$category->term_id}' />&nbsp;";

        $output .= "<label for='adv_cat_{$category->term_id}'><span></span>$category->name</label>";

        if ( isset($show_count) && $show_count )
            $output .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')';

        if ( isset($show_date) && $show_date )
            $output  .= ' ' . gmdate('Y-m-d', $category->last_update_timestamp);
    }

    function end_el($output, $page, $depth, $args) {
        if ( 'list' != $args['style'] )
            return $output;

        $output .= "</li>\n";
        return $output;
    }
}

function adv_cats($args = '') {
        $defaults = array(
            'show_option_all' => '?', 
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'show_last_update' => 0,
            'style' => 'list', 
            'show_count' => 1,
            'hide_empty' => 0, 
            'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
            'child_of' => 0, 
            'feed' => '',
            'feed_image' => '', 
            'exclude' => '',
            'hierarchical' => true, 
            'title_li' => '',
            'echo' => 0
        );

        $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

        if ( !isset( $r['pad_counts'] ) && $r['show_count'] && $r['hierarchical'] ) {
            $r['pad_counts'] = true;
        }

        if ( isset( $r['show_date'] ) ) {
            $r['include_last_update_time'] = $r['show_date'];
        }

        extract( $r );

        $categories = get_categories($r);

        $output = '';
        if ( $title_li && 'list' == $style )
                $output = '<li class="categories">' . $r['title_li'] . '<ul>';

        if ( empty($categories) ) {
            if ( 'list' == $style )
                $output .= '<li>' . __("No categories", "WPL") . '</li>';
            else
                $output .= __("No categories", "WPL");
        } else {
            global $wp_query;

                if( !empty($show_option_all) )
                if ('list' == $style )

        $output .= "<li><input type='checkbox' class='checkall'  checked='checked' name='checkall' id='checkall' />&nbsp;";

        $output .= "<label for='checkall'><span></span>".__('Check/Uncheck All', 'WPL').'</label>';

            if ( is_category() )
                $r['current_category'] = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

            if ( $hierarchical )
                $depth = 0;  // Walk the full depth.
            else
                $depth = -1; // Flat.

            $output .= $this->walk_category_tree($categories, $depth, $r);
        }

        if ( $title_li && 'list' == $style )
            $output .= '</ul></li>';

        $output = apply_filters('wp_list_categories', $output);

    return '<ul>' . $output . '</ul>';
    }

    function walk_category_tree() {
        $walker = new Adv_Multicheck_Walker_Category;
        $args = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array(array(&$walker, 'walk'), $args);
    }
```

Then download this http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

Then init this plugin by the div where one create the output in checkbox, like:

```
$('#adv_search_form .multicheck-cats').tree({ components: ['checkbox', 'collapse'], onCheck: { node: 'expand', ancestors: 'checkIfFull', descendants: 'check' }, onUncheck: { node: 'collapse', ancestors: 'uncheck' } });
```

And here is a live Preview:

http://pro.at-tanzil.de/erweiterte-suche-2/